# Visual Studios 2015 - new form anchored in place

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I'm using VS 2015 Community edition. I've started a brand new project and am looking at the Forms Designer. The default form 1 is located in the upper left corner. 
I want to move it to the center of the screen.

I can't.

Properties starting position is set to center screen.
I've checked all instances of the lock controls that I can find and the form is not locked.
I've even tried editing the x,y location values in the form properties.

Nothing will get this form to move from the position that it is currently anchored in.
I can resize it, but I can't move it.

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Think about it this way.  If you wanted to paint a picture on a canvas to hang on the center of your wall, you would still start painting at the top-left of the canvas, you would just hang the canvas in middle once it is done and dry.  That's what the form designer is, it is a "canvas" that gets positioned on the screen when the program runs.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but is there no way to relocate the form while in the designer? The only reason I'm even curious about it, is that the toolbox covers up the form when its open. I can move the toolbox around, I guess, but it just seemed to make more sense to me to move the form itself.

Comment: If you pin the toolbox it will move the design surface so it is no longer under the designer.

Comment: Alright. That's all I was really curious about and couldn't really find an answer online. Thanks for help.